# How to group date by day and find min and max value in pandas data frame or python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, max, min

[Two event  columns dtb(start time) dte(stop time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD7s0.png)

In the image two columns is there I want group by day of the value for get min(time) as start of the event on the day and get max(time) as stop of the event on the day.[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rgws.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the guidelines about `how to ask`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then edit your post and provide more informations like stuff you already tried and / or code. We're helping you with problem you get on the way to your application but we don't program stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to do my best to answer it as I understood it.

Supposing your columns `dtb` and `dte` are in `datetime` format:

```
df['date'] = df.dtb.dt.date
df['dtb'] = df.dtb.dt.time
df['dte'] = df.dte.dt.time

result = df.groupby('date').agg({'dtb': np.max,
                                'dte': np.min})
print(result)
```

What I did is create a new column with the date, and reformat the `dtb` and `dte` columns to get only the time, and then group by the date taking the max and min for `dtb` and `dte`

Comment: Yes, Your understanding is correct. But now I'm getting this ERROR: Type-error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Ok, now I tested the answer, check the edit. What I did is suppose that in every row you have the same date for the start and the end. So create a new column with the date, and then reformat the start and the end with the time only

Answer (score 0):

You can directly group per day or per week even using the following syntax

```
dg_bydate= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dtb', freq='1D')).agg({'dte':[np.min, np.max]})
```